# ODBC_result_all bad print

Tags: php, sql, odbc, fpdf

I'm actually working on a database SQL Server on Windows.
I access it with ODBC in PHP.
I use FPDF because I want to print mySQL answer on a PDF who's generate when I launch my code.

That's a bit of my code:

```
$rs=odbc_exec ($connection, $query);
$print=odbc_result_all($rs, "cellpadding= '3' background-color = 'd3d3d3'");
/////
$pdf->Write(20,$print);
$pdf->Text(100,100,$print);
```

First of all, I can print the SQL answer on my web page and I can print text on my PDF.

So I want to print the SQL answer on the PDF, but when I execute my code, he prints the number of results...

I don't understand why. Maybe that's a type problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is converting in HTML so you have to use

```
$pdf->WriteHTML($print)
```

Something like above for HTML data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, FPDF doesn't have a "WriteHTML" like. I'll try with another librairies, FTPDF has that method if I remember well.

Comment: @Romain you can create function something like this reference from fpdf site http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script42.php or you may use other options like mpdf, tcpdf etc.

Comment: I just saw it yes! I think it's the only solution if I want to continue to using FPDF

Comment: If you are in the initial stage of development you may change because may in future another thing will cause an issue in development.

Comment: Oh okay, what do you recommend? Or maybe they're all with the same "level"?

Comment: I use FTPDF now, I used writeHTML() but it continues to print the number of results, I really don't understand